# Uiview with close "x" button

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to create a UIView programmatically, and want a close "X" button at the top left vertice of the View. When i press the close button view disappears. Is it possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a button with frame CGRect (0, 0, 20, 20), then add it to the view. [UIView addSubView]
set the target of the button.

```
UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I think you mean ```UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];```